# Finding all classes "B" in Class "A" in XPath

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I have trouble finding the right XPath for a program I am writing.
The XML is something like this:

```
<root>
    <div class"XYZ">
        <div>
            <div class = "abc">
                <a class = "important">Important Information - 1</a>
            </div>
            <div class = "abc">
                <a class = "important">Important Information - 2</a>
            </div>
            <div class = "abc">
                <a class = "important">Important Information - 3</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</root>
```

So, as you can see, there is a class I need to go "XYZ" and in that class there are many classes named "abc". In reality there are more `<div>` in front of the class "abc".

I need to get every "Important Information - X".

My idea was

```
FindElements(By.XPath("//*[contains(@class,'XYZ')]/*[contains(@class,'important')]");
```

The problem why I can't just search for the class = "important" itself is, that there is another part in the document, which has the same class name but I don't need that information. Only the ones in the class "XYZ".

When I only use:

```
FindElements(By.XPath("//*[contains(@class,'XYZ')]");
```

it works, but I get a lot of unimportant information too, since there is more stuff in the `<div>`s.

Comment: Replace the `/*` in the middle with `//*`?

Comment: Damn...it worked xD

Comment: Pro-tips for posting: once you get an answer to your question, please do not edit it to ask another one. We need to ensure that edits do not invalidate answers already given, so ask a new question, linking back here if appropriate. Secondly, we don't use [solved] title hacks here - the acceptance/tick system should be used instead. Finally, please try to refrain from a chatty style - a technical problem is not "more drama". Thanks!

Comment: Well, in my defense, I wanted to write "problem" but it seems that it is blacklisted... forced me to be a bit more creative

Answer (score 1):

One solution suggested in the comments is

```
FindElements(By.XPath("//*[contains(@class,'XYZ')]//*[contains(@class,'important')]");
```